# Parse IRC into XML

Tags: code-golf

Here's an example IRC log (this will be your program's input):

```
[01:00] == User [*****] has joined #Channel
[01:00] == ChanServ [ChanServ@services.] has left #Channel []
[01:00] == mode/#Channel [+o User] by ChanServ
[01:00] <Bot> Welcome, User!
[01:01] <User> Hello bot
[01:02] <Bot> Hi there
[01:38] <OtherUser> I like pie
[01:38] <User> Me too :D
[19:58] <@Mod> I am a mod!!!1!!11!
[19:59] <User> That's fascinating
```

Your task is to parse that into XML, like this (this will be your program's output):

```
<irc>
  <message type='event'>
    <text>User [*****] has joined #Channel</text>
    <time>01:00</time>
  </message>
  ...
  <message type='chat'>
    <user>Bot</user>
    <text>Welcome, User!</text>
    <time>01:00</time>
  </message>
  ...
</irc>
```

Further specification:

- must be well-formed XML (except for the XML declaration at the top), whitespace/indentation unnecessary
- you don't have to worry about escaping; `>`, `<`, etc. will never appear in messages
- messages can be in two forms:

  - `[{hh:mm}] <{username}> {message}`

    - this should be parsed as:

      ```
      <message type='chat'>
        <user>{username}</user>
        <text>{message}</text>
        <time>{hh:mm}</time>
      </message>
      ```
  - `[{hh:mm}] == {message}`

    - this should be parsed as:

      ```
      <message type='event'>
        <text>{message}</text>
        <time>{hh:mm}</time>
      </message>
      ```
- XML consists of a single `irc` element with zero or more `message` elements in it
- order of the elements within the `message` element don't matter, but order of `message` elements does
- input and output can be any reasonable method (i.e. stdin and stdout, reading from/writing to files, etc.) but input cannot be hardcoded
- this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins

Comment: XML cannot be *valid* unless it refers to a specific DTD, which you have not provided. Perhaps you should only specify that it be well-formed?

Comment: How about using XML libraries/built-in functions in languages that have them? Is that allowed?

Comment: @marinus why not? I used Nokogiri in the Google-scraping task.

Comment: @KevinReid Okay, I have edited the question.

Comment: @marinus They are not explicitly disallowed, so yes.

Comment: Reviving the dead here:  How did this question get so few views, and 3 downvotes?  Does nobody like xml or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 140 characters

```
{.@+'<>'1/*@+\'</>'2/*+}:^;n%{" "/(1>5<'''time'^\(.'='>{;'event'}{1>-1<'''user'^@+\'chat'}if`' type='\+\' '*'''text'^@+\'message'^}%'''irc'^
```

I meant to use a language, especially designed for xml processing. Input/output is STDIN/STDOUT. You can remove a few chars by replacing `''` with `n` but that makes the output more unreadable.

Output for the example given above ([online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJbMDE6MDBdID09IFVzZXIgWyoqKioqXSBoYXMgam9pbmVkICNDaGFubmVsClswMTowMF0gPT0gQ2hhblNlcnYgW0NoYW5TZXJ2QHNlcnZpY2VzLl0gaGFzIGxlZnQgI0NoYW5uZWwgW10KWzAxOjAwXSA9PSBtb2RlLyNDaGFubmVsIFsrbyBVc2VyXSBieSBDaGFuU2VydgpbMDE6MDBdIDxCb3Q%2BIFdlbGNvbWUsIFVzZXIhClswMTowMV0gPFVzZXI%2BIEhlbGxvIGJvdApbMDE6MDJdIDxCb3Q%2BIEhpIHRoZXJlClswMTozOF0gPE90aGVyVXNlcj4gSSBsaWtlIHBpZQpbMDE6MzhdIDxVc2VyPiBNZSB0b28gOkQKWzE5OjU4XSA8QE1vZD4gSSBhbSBhIG1vZCEhITEhITExIQpbMTk6NTldIDxVc2VyPiBUaGF0J3MgZmFzY2luYXRpbmcKIgoKey5AKyc8PicxLypAK1wnPC8%2BJzIvKit9Ol47biV7IiAiLygxPjU8JycndGltZSdeXCguJz0nPns7J2V2ZW50J317MT4tMTwnJyd1c2VyJ15AK1wnY2hhdCd9aWZgJyB0eXBlPSdcK1wnICcqJycndGV4dCdeQCtcJ21lc3NhZ2UnXn0lJycnaXJjJ14%3D&run=true)):

```
<irc><message type="event"><text>User [*****] has joined #Channel</text><time>01:00</time></message><message type="event"><text>ChanServ [ChanServ@services.] has left #Channel []</text><time>01:00</time></message><message type="event"><text>mode/#Channel [+o User] by ChanServ</text><time>01:00</time></message><message type="chat"><text>Welcome, User!</text><user>Bot</user><time>01:00</time></message><message type="chat"><text>Hello bot</text><user>User</user><time>01:01</time></message><message type="chat"><text>Hi there</text><user>Bot</user><time>01:02</time></message><message type="chat"><text>I like pie</text><user>OtherUser</user><time>01:38</time></message><message type="chat"><text>Me too :D</text><user>User</user><time>01:38</time></message><message type="chat"><text>I am a mod!!!1!!11!</text><user>@Mod</user><time>19:58</time></message><message type="chat"><text>That's fascinating</text><user>User</user><time>19:59</time></message></irc>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Tcl, 268

I believe Perl would be better for the job, but who cares.

```
puts <irc>[regsub -all -line {^\[([^\]]*)\] == (.*$)} [regsub -all -line {^\[([^\]]*)\] <([^>]*)> (.*)} [gets stdin] {<message type='chat'><user>\2</user><text>\3</text><time>\1</time></message>}] {<message type='event'><text>\2</text><time>\1</time></message>}]</irc>
```

Every task that can be solved with 2 regsub is boring.

Answer (score 1):

#### R 254 characters

```
cat("<irc>",gsub("\\[(.*)\\] <(.*)> (.*)","<message type=\\'chat\\'><user>\\2</user><text>\\3</text><time>\\1</time></message>",gsub("\\[(.*)\\] == (.*)","<message type=\\'event\\'><text>\\2</text><time>\\1</time></message>",scan(,"",se="\n"))),"</irc>")
```

Very simple solution: take input as newline-separated stdin, apply two `gsub` to it (one for events, one for chats) and output.

Example output with example input from question:

```
<irc> <message type='event'><text>User [*****] has joined #Channel</text><time>01:00</time></message <message type='event'><text>ChanServ [ChanServ@services.] has left #Channel []</text><time>01:00</time></message <message type='event'><text>mode/#Channel [+o User] by ChanServ</text><time>01:00</time></message <message type='chat'><user>Bot</user><text>Welcome, User!</text><time>01:00</time></message <message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>Hello bot</text><time>01:01</time></message <message type='chat'><user>Bot</user><text>Hi there</text><time>01:02</time></message <message type='chat'><user>OtherUser</user><text>I like pie</text><time>01:38</time></message <message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>Me too :D</text><time>01:38</time></message <message type='chat'><user>@Mod</user><text>I am a mod!!!1!!11!</text><time>19:58</time></message <message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>That's fascinating</text><time>19:59</time></message </irc>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby: 186 characters

```ruby
BEGIN{puts"<irc>"}
END{puts"</irc>"}
sub(/.(.{5}). (<(.+?)>|==) (.+)/){"<message type='#{$3?:chat:"event"}'>#{$3?"<user>#{$3}</user>":""}<text>#{$4}</text><time>#{$1}</time></message>"}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -p irc2xml.rb < irc.txt
<irc>
<message type='event'><text>User [*****] has joined #Channel</text><time>01:00</time></message>
<message type='event'><text>ChanServ [ChanServ@services.] has left #Channel []</text><time>01:00</time></message>
<message type='event'><text>mode/#Channel [+o User] by ChanServ</text><time>01:00</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>Bot</user><text>Welcome, User!</text><time>01:00</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>Hello bot</text><time>01:01</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>Bot</user><text>Hi there</text><time>01:02</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>OtherUser</user><text>I like pie</text><time>01:38</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>Me too :D</text><time>01:38</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>@Mod</user><text>I am a mod!!!1!!11!</text><time>19:58</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>That's fascinating</text><time>19:59</time></message>
</irc>
```

Test run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -p irc2xml.rb < irc.txt | xmlstarlet val -
- - valid
```

Comment: You have to remove `== ` from the event text.

Comment: Oops. Missed that. Thank you, @Howard.

Answer (score 1):

## Sed: <s>183</s> 180 characters

```
1i<irc>
s!.(.{5}). (.*)!\2<time>\1</time>!
Ta
s!<(.+?)> (.*)!chat\n\2<user>\1</user>!
ta
s!== !event\n!
:a
s!(.+)\n([^<]+)!<message type='\1'><text>\2</text>!
a</message>
$a</irc>
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ sed -rf irc2xml.sed < irc.txt
<irc>
<message type='event'><text>User [*****] has joined #Channel</text><time>01:00</time>
</message>
<message type='event'><text>ChanServ [ChanServ@services.] has left #Channel []</text><time>01:00</time>
</message>
<message type='event'><text>mode/#Channel [+o User] by ChanServ</text><time>01:00</time>
</message>
<message type='chat'><text>Welcome, User!</text><time>01:00</time><user>Bot</user>
</message>
<message type='chat'><text>Hello bot</text><time>01:01</time><user>User</user>
</message>
<message type='chat'><text>Hi there</text><time>01:02</time><user>Bot</user>
</message>
<message type='chat'><text>I like pie</text><time>01:38</time><user>OtherUser</user>
</message>
<message type='chat'><text>Me too :D</text><time>01:38</time><user>User</user>
</message>
<message type='chat'><text>I am a mod!!!1!!11!</text><time>19:58</time><user>@Mod</user>
</message>
<message type='chat'><text>That"s fascinating</text><time>19:59</time><user>User</user>
</message>
</irc>
```

Test run:

```
bash-4.1$ sed -rf irc2xml.sed < irc.txt | xmlstarlet val -
- - valid
```

Comment: You omitted the message type from your output.

Comment: Ouch. I'm not on top today. Thanks again, @Howard.

Answer (score 0):

## Awk: 203 characters

```awk
BEGIN{print"<irc>"}END{print"</irc>"}{gsub(/\[|\]/,"",$1)
$2=gsub(/<|>/,"",$2)?"<user>"$2"</user>":""
$1="<message type='"($2?"chat":"event")"'><time>"$1"</time>"
$3="<text>"$3
$0=$0"</text></message>"}1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ awk -f irc2xml.awk < irc.txt
<irc>
<message type='event'><time>01:00</time>  <text>User [*****] has joined #Channel</text></message>
<message type='event'><time>01:00</time>  <text>ChanServ [ChanServ@services.] has left #Channel []</text></message>
<message type='event'><time>01:00</time>  <text>mode/#Channel [+o User] by ChanServ</text></message>
<message type='chat'><time>01:00</time> <user>Bot</user> <text>Welcome, User!</text></message>
<message type='chat'><time>01:01</time> <user>User</user> <text>Hello bot</text></message>
<message type='chat'><time>01:02</time> <user>Bot</user> <text>Hi there</text></message>
<message type='chat'><time>01:38</time> <user>OtherUser</user> <text>I like pie</text></message>
<message type='chat'><time>01:38</time> <user>User</user> <text>Me too :D</text></message>
<message type='chat'><time>19:58</time> <user>@Mod</user> <text>I am a mod!!!1!!11!</text></message>
<message type='chat'><time>19:59</time> <user>User</user> <text>That"s fascinating</text></message>
</irc>
```

Test run:

```
bash-4.1$ awk -f irc2xml.awk < irc.txt | xmlstarlet val -
- - valid
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl: 168 characters

```perl
BEGIN{say"<irc>"}END{say"</irc>"}/.(.{5}). (<(.+?)>|==) (.+)/;say"<message type='",$3?chat:event,"'>",$3&&"<user>$3</user>","<text>$4</text><time>$1</time></message>"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ perl -nE 'BEGIN{say"<irc>"}END{say"</irc>"}/.(.{5}). (<(.+?)>|==) (.+)/;say"<message type='"'"'",$3?chat:event,"'"'"'>",$3&&"<user>$3</user>","<text>$4</text><time>$1</time></message>"' < irc.txt
<irc>
<message type='event'><text>User [*****] has joined #Channel</text><time>01:00</time></message>
<message type='event'><text>ChanServ [ChanServ@services.] has left #Channel []</text><time>01:00</time></message>
<message type='event'><text>mode/#Channel [+o User] by ChanServ</text><time>01:00</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>Bot</user><text>Welcome, User!</text><time>01:00</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>Hello bot</text><time>01:01</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>Bot</user><text>Hi there</text><time>01:02</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>OtherUser</user><text>I like pie</text><time>01:38</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>Me too :D</text><time>01:38</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>@Mod</user><text>I am a mod!!!1!!11!</text><time>19:58</time></message>
<message type='chat'><user>User</user><text>That's fascinating</text><time>19:59</time></message>
</irc>
```

Test run:

```
bash-4.1$ perl -nE 'BEGIN{say"<irc>"}END{say"</irc>"}/.(.{5}). (<(.+?)>|==) (.+)/;say"<message type='"'"'",$3?chat:event,"'"'"'>",$3&&"<user>$3</user>","<text>$4</text><time>$1</time></message>"' < irc.txt | xmlstarlet val -
- - valid
```